# Clearing context in canvas html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to draw a photo in a canvas and allow the user to drag a circle over it. I'm able to do it. The problem is when I clear context, the image I had drawn is gone (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/wL0ossth/) and if don't clear context the whole image is being filled with coloured circles (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/wL0ossth/1/). Some code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
    <img id="scream" src="http://i10.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/655x588/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2014/11/25/2324_bus.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JavaScript: 'http://jsfiddle.net/wL0ossth/1/

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
     var img=document.getElementById("scream");  
     var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
     ctx.drawImage(img,10,10); 
 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', followMouse, false);  

function findOffset(obj) {
    var curX = curY = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curX += obj.offsetLeft;
            curY += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return {x:curX,y:curY};
    }
}

function followMouse(e){


    ctx.beginPath();
    var offset = findOffset(canvas);   //get the offset of the canvas relative to the page

    var posX = e.pageX - offset.x;     //find the x position of the mouse
    var posY = e.pageY - offset.y;     //find the y position of the mouse

    ctx.arc(posX,posY,50,0,Math.PI*2,false);   //draw a circle
    ctx.fill(); 
}
```

Edited: I want to make the circle movable with cleared context along with image I drew. In short, a circle without leaving blackish trail in path as is drawn in http://jsfiddle.net/wL0ossth/1/

Comment: Please clarify: What do you want to happen when the user moves the circle with the mouse?

Comment: Actually,simply dragging circle with context clear so that once drawn will not show as it is showing in http://jsfiddle.net/wL0ossth/1/ along with img drawed as background.

Comment: @soktinpk has your fix! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this (although I'm not sure unless you clarify your post a bit):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var img = document.getElementById("scream");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', followMouse, false);

  function findOffset(obj) {
    var curX = 0,
        curY = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
      do {
        curX += obj.offsetLeft;
        curY += obj.offsetTop;
      } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
      return {
        x: curX,
        y: curY
      };
    }
  }

  function followMouse(e) {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10); // Notice I moved the image down to here
    ctx.beginPath();
    var offset = findOffset(canvas); //get the offset of the canvas relative to the page

    var posX = e.pageX - offset.x; //find the x position of the mouse
    var posY = e.pageY - offset.y; //find the y position of the mouse

    ctx.arc(posX, posY, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false); //draw a circle
    ctx.fill();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<img id="scream" src="http://i10.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/655x588/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2014/11/25/2324_bus.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">
```

What you need to do is put `drawImage(img)` after the `clearRect`. That way every time the canvas is cleared, the image is drawn again.

Comment: Agreed, `clearRect` plus `drawImage` sounds like it will do the trick.

Comment: @soktinpk I really appreciate your method for solving problem.Gracias!!